# Tamaño de campos de una tabla varían

Tags: php, html, css

Tengo una situación muy extraña.

Desde una página selecciono condiciones para mostrar una tabla, cuando muestro la tabla, si las condiciones venían en blanco me la muestra bien, pero si las condiciones traen valor el tamaño de los items no es el mismo.

Cuando me trae la lista entera sale así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es lo que quiero siempre.

Pero cuando selecciono algún complejo, y trae menos datos, cambia así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pareciera que mientras más datos menos tamaño, no le encuentro el sentido. Esto empezó a ocurrir cuando hise los cambios para que apareciera el scroll.

El código de la parte donde defino la tabla es el siguiente:

```
<p align="center">
     <table id="Unidades" class="BlueNoteFormTABLE" cellpadding="2" WIDTH=100% style="display: block;">
      <thead  style="position:relative; display: block; width: calc( 100% - 1em );">
       <tr valign="top">
      <td class="BlueNoteColumnTD" WIDTH=5% nowrap ></td> 

      <td class="BlueNoteColumnTD" WIDTH=25% nowrap >
        <!-- BEGIN Sorter Sorter_unit_no -->
         <a class="BlueNoteSorterLink" href="<?php echo './Unit_List.php?'.$param."&O=C"; ?>">Complex</a> 
        <!-- BEGIN Asc_On --><img src="Themes/BlueNote/AscOn.gif" border="0" width="8" height="6"><!-- END Asc_On -->
        <!-- BEGIN Desc_On --><img src="Themes/BlueNote/DescOn.gif" border="0" width="8" height="6"><!-- END Desc_On --><!-- END Sorter Sorter_unit_no -->&nbsp;</td> 
      <td class="BlueNoteColumnTD"  WIDTH=10% nowrap >
        <!-- BEGIN Sorter Sorter_unit_no --><a class="BlueNoteSorterLink" href="<?php echo './Unit_List.php?'.$param."&O=U"; ?>">Unit</a> 
        <!-- BEGIN Asc_On --><img src="Themes/BlueNote/AscOn.gif" border="0" width="8" height="6"><!-- END Asc_On -->
        <!-- BEGIN Desc_On --><img src="Themes/BlueNote/DescOn.gif" border="0" width="8" height="6"><!-- END Desc_On --><!-- END Sorter Sorter_unit_no -->&nbsp;</td> 
      <td class="BlueNoteColumnTD"  WIDTH=25% nowrap >
        <!-- BEGIN Sorter Sorter_sect_title_no --><a class="BlueNoteSorterLink" href="<?php echo './Unit_List.php?'.$param."&O=S"; ?>">Section</a> 
        <!-- BEGIN Asc_On --><img src="Themes/BlueNote/AscOn.gif" border="0" width="8" height="6"><!-- END Asc_On -->
        <!-- BEGIN Desc_On --><img src="Themes/BlueNote/DescOn.gif" border="0" width="8" height="6"><!-- END Desc_On --><!-- END Sorter Sorter_sect_title_no --></td> 
      <td class="BlueNoteColumnTD"  WIDTH=35% nowrap >
        <!-- BEGIN Sorter Sorter_owner --><a class="BlueNoteSorterLink" href="<?php echo './Unit_List.php?'.$param."&O=O"; ?>">Owner</a> 
        <!-- BEGIN Asc_On --><img src="Themes/BlueNote/AscOn.gif" border="0" width="8" height="6"><!-- END Asc_On -->
        <!-- BEGIN Desc_On --><img src="Themes/BlueNote/DescOn.gif" border="0" width="8" height="6"><!-- END Desc_On --><!-- END Sorter Sorter_owner --></td> 


    </tr>
      </thead>
      <!-- BEGIN Row -->
      <tbody WIDTH=100% style="display: block;  height:400px;  overflow:scroll;">
    <?php
      for ($i=0; $i<=$CountList-1; $i++) {

          $fila = $i + 1;
          echo "<tr valign='top' WIDTH=100%>";

          echo '<td  bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  style="border-style:ridge; border-width:2px;"  WIDTH=5%>';

          echo '<a class="BlueNoteDataLink"  href="#" onclick="return ListarActividades(';

          echo $ListUnit["records"][$i]['unit_id'] . ', ' . $fila ;

          echo ');">act</a></td>'; 

          echo '<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  style="border-style:ridge; border-width:2px;" WIDTH=25%><a class="BlueNoteDataLink" href="">';

          $Comp = new Complex($DB);
          echo $Comp -> GetName($DB, $ListUnit["records"][$i]['complex_id']);

          echo '</a></td>';

           echo '<td  bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  style="border-style:ridge; border-width:2px;" WIDTH=10%><a class="BlueNoteDataLink" href="#"  onclick="return OpenUnit(';

          echo $ListUnit["records"][$i]['unit_id'];

          echo ');">';

          echo $ListUnit["records"][$i]['unit_no'];

          echo '</a></td> ';

          echo '<td  bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  style="border-style:ridge; border-width:2px;" WIDTH=25%><a class="BlueNoteDataLink" href="#"  onclick="return OpenUnit(';

          echo $ListUnit["records"][$i]['unit_id'];

          echo ');">';

          echo $ListUnit["records"][$i]['sect_title_no'];

          echo '</a></td> ';

          echo '<td  WIDTH=35% bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  style="border-style:ridge; border-width:2px;">';
          echo '<p style="font-size: 9px;" >';
          echo $ListUnit["records"][$i]['o_name'];
          echo '</p>';

          echo '</td> '; 

          echo "</tr>";
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme, si les ha pasado algo parecido o ven donde tengo el error, me harían un gran favor.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tiene, es que asignaste el tamaño de las filas en porcentajes, por lo tanto dependienta del texto que se imprima en la fila, va a variar su tamaño. La solución es colarle un tamaño fijo y alterarlo con @media screens.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Trata de ampliar tu respuesta para que sirva de referencia para futuros visitantes. Tal y como está, mas parece un comentario y esta no es la sección adecuada para hacerlos. Haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te enteres de lo que te hablo.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias lo tomare en cuenta en futuras respuestas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. O sea que sería mejor usar witdh="10px", por ejemplo?

Comment: Ok, aparte de eso, tuve que colocar en los estilos de la tabla table-layout: fixed; y en los de los td word-wrap: break-word;

Comment: @MaríaDelPilarFernández, exacto, puedes usar eso estilos para ajustar el tamaño de las tablas, [por aquí te dejo este enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_table-layout) referente a los que deseas hacer.